# (Python) Recreating Effects applied to Image for Template Matching

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, template-matching

I've been working with Python's opencv library, and am having some trouble getting it to recognize some images.

To summarize the issue, I have hundreds of images pulled from a game. I am attempting to use `matchTemplate()` to find these images on the screen at various times, but it appears that the game applies some smoothing/blurring to the images before they're displayed.

[image: Image from Game Files]

*^ Original Image from Game Files*

I first attempted to match the techniques by resizing the image downward using Pillow's `Image.resize()` method, but there was still a clear difference.

[image: Image comparisons]

*(Top to Bottom) Image from Game Files After Pillow Resize -> Image Taken in the Game*

I've attempted to use Pillow library's methods of blurring to get the image recognized, but the max confidence I can get with this is about 0.3.

Does anybody have any suggestions for ways to programmatically edit these images with python to be reliably recognizable with `matchTemplate()`? I'm not attached to OpenCV, so different methods/libraries relevant to solving my problem are welcome if anyone has better ideas!

Comment: Post your code! And your original image and template.

Comment: Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).